# Testing a database response in an Angularjs/Jasmine test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm attempting to unit test an angular factory in jasmine but I'm having trouble understanding how to get an actual response from my database.

I have the following factory code that retrieves an object containing company information based on a company ticker value.

The factory works fine but I'd like to test it in jasmine.

```
    app.factory('adminOps',function($http, $log, $q){
      return {
        getByTicker: function(ticker){

            return $http.post("http://localhost:3000/ticker", {"ticker": ticker})
            .then(function(response){
                if (typeof response.data === 'object') {
                    return response.data;
                } else {
                    return $q.reject(response.data);
                }

            }, function(response) {
                return $q.reject(response);
            });
        }
      };
    });
```

To test this I have the following jasmine code based on online examples I found.

```
describe('adminOps', function() {
  var factory, http;

  beforeEach(module('myApp'));
  beforeEach(inject(function(_adminOps_, $httpBackend) {
    factory = _adminOps_;
    http = $httpBackend;
  }));

  it('Should retrieve company data', function(done) {
    var testCompany = function(company) {
      expect(company.name).toBe("Google Inc.");
    };

    var failTest = function(error) {
      expect(error).toBeUndefined();
    }

    http.expectPOST('http://localhost:3000/ticker',{ticker:"GOOG"}).respond(200, {ticker:"GOOG"});

    factory.getByTicker("GOOG")
      .then(testCompany)
      .catch(failTest)
      .finally(done);

    http.flush();
  });
});
```

I get a `Expected undefined to be 'Google Inc.'`.

How can I call my factory and test for the correct name value for the ticker parameter I send?

UPDATE: Koen's code works correctly. I've found if you want to test values on a server, like a rest api, then you should try something like [frisby](https://github.com/vlucas/frisby), which is built on Jasmine.

Comment: Unit tests use a **mock** $httpBackend. This **mock** $httpBackend doesn't send any request. It's precisely used to avoid sending http requests. It only answers what the unit tests tell it to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unittests should test your local code and should not have external dependencies. Therefor your test doesn't and shouldn't actually access your database.

$httpBackend allows you to mock the http request and response.

Your code mocks the $httpBackend as follows:

```
http.expectPOST('http://localhost:3000/ticker',{
    ticker:"GOOG"
}).respond(200,{
    ticker:"GOOG"
});
```

meaning it will respond with a response of

```
{ticker:"GOOG"}
```

So it doesn't have the 'name' attribute you need.

A proper way to test your 'getByTicker' method is with the following $httpBackend setup:

```
$http.expectPOST('http://localhost:3000/ticker', {
  ticker: "GOOG"
}).respond(200, {
  name: "Google Inc."
});
```